# Posting to a controller via Html.BeginForm() with Complex Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The title of the Q says it all, I've read many posts and still cannot get my head around this. All I'm trying to do is `Post` an object with nested objects. The core object populates fine but the nested objects always returns null.

The backend/ViewModel as such:

```
public class EntityExtendedProperty
{
    public ExtendedPropertyDefinition Definition { get; set; }
    //Type above contains Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions
}
```

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditExtendedProperty(EntityExtendedProperty vm)
{
    //Can I access View Model here?
    var v = vm; // I debug here
}
```

The Front-End:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditExtendedProperty","Organisation",FormMethod.Post, new {vm = Model }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Definition.Id)

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Edit Extended Property</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Area :</td>
                        <td>@Model.Definition.ExtendedPropertyEntityType.Name</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Definition.Title)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>IsEnumerated</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Definition.IsEnumerated)</td>
                        @if(Model.Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions.Any())
                        {
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr><th>Options</th></tr>
                                @foreach(var o in Model.Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions)
                                {
                                    <tr><td>@Html.EditorFor(m => o.Title)</td></tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        }   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>AllowMultiSelect</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Definition.AllowMultiSelect)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>IsDate</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Definition.IsDate)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As you can see, this is all relatively straight forward but why is `ExtendedPropertyOptions` values returning null?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `ExtendedPropertyOptions` si a complex object, then its `EditorFor(m => m.ExtendedPropertyOptions)` (no loop) and you create an `EditorTemplate` for the type. Alternatively use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the data that is posted in looks correct in something like chrome network tab - I think that it should look like

```
Definition.Title: "Hello"
Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions[0].Property: "a"
Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions[1].Property: "b"
```

you may have to use some other way to pass in the html prefix to the child objects or use that and partial views to set TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix

Answer (score 2):

your editor should look like:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr><td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Definition.ExtendedPropertyOptions[i].Title)</td></tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I'm not entirely sure why changing to a "for" loop would fix the issue?

Comment: The values are still null - any suggestions?

Comment: @TezWingfield `for` looping is to get index of item. check modelState for errors.